# Updating the text of NSTextField from another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've noticed that I am unable to update the text on my NSTextField:

```
mainClass.h
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSTextField *titleLabel; 

mainClass.m    

-(void)viewDidLoad {
LabelClass *element = [[LabelClass alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:[element label:self.titleLabel title:@"My label" xCoord:0 yCoord:0 width:100 height:50]];
}
```

Now if try to update the NSTextField text, it doesn't work:

```
mainClass.m

-(void)someMethod{
[self.titleLabel setStringValue:@"Updated text"];
}
```

I think it's important to note that the 'self.titleLabel' property was created in the current class that I am trying to update my label 'mainClass.m'. The class that I am calling my label from 'LabelClass.m' just holds the method that creates the label, so I've simply created an instance of that class, created the label and set 'self.titleLabel':

```
LabelClass.m

@implementation LabelClass

-(NSTextField *)label:(NSTextField *)label title:(NSString *)title xCoord:(CGFloat)x yCoord:(CGFloat)y width:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height{
    NSTextField *textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    [textField setStringValue:title];
    [textField setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];
    [textField setEditable:NO];
    [textField setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [textField setSelectable:NO];
    [textField setBezeled:NO];
    return textField;
}
```

Comment: `UILabel` is for iOS. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Ah, crap you're right. I meant NSTextField! Dammit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    LabelClass *element = [[LabelClass alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:[element label:self.titleLabel title:@"My label" xCoord:0 yCoord:0 width:100 height:50]];
}
```

You're returning a `NSTextField` from the call to `LabelClass`, but you're never assigning it to your `self.titleLabel`. Try this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    LabelClass *element = [[LabelClass alloc] init];
    self.titleLabel = [element labelWithTitle:@"My Label" xCoord:0 yCoord:0 width:100 height:50];
    [self.view addSubview:self.titleLabel];
}
```

Then modify your `label:title:xCoord:yCoord:width:height:` method to remove the label parameter, since you're not passing one in, you're returning one.

```
-(NSTextField *)labelWithTitle:(NSString *)title xCoord:(CGFloat)x yCoord:(CGFloat)y width:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height{
    NSTextField *textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    [textField setStringValue:title];
    [textField setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];
    [textField setEditable:NO];
    [textField setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [textField setSelectable:NO];
    [textField setBezeled:NO];
    return textField;
}
```

Comment: The OP had a big typo - it's a Cocoa question about `NSTextField`.

Comment: Yeah, this was the answer. If you could update your answer so we don't confuse other users. I will give you credit once it's updated. Thanks, Simon!

Comment: There you go! I hope that's what you were looking for :)